# Integer vs Int trouble in Haskell function

Tags: haskell

I have the following function that will recursively multiply the digits of a number until it reaches a single digit number

```
multResWithCounter' :: (Int, [Int],[Integer]) -> (Int, [Int],[Integer])
multResWithCounter' (counter, listOfDigits,listOfProducts)
   | (length listOfDigits) <= 1 = (counter, listOfDigits, listOfProducts)
   | otherwise = multResWithCounter' ((counter + 1), newListOfDigits, digitProduct:listOfProducts)
   where newListOfDigits = map (\n -> read [n] :: Int) (show $ digitProduct)
         digitProduct = ((product listOfDigits) :: Integer)
```

Which of course doesn't compile in ghci, complaining that it couldn't match expected type Integer with actual type Int.
If I back down and change the type declaration to Int and call it, this way for example,

```
multResWithCounter' (0,[2,7,7,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,8,8,8,9,9],[])
```

I get

```
(2,[0],[0,1191706624])
```

Now this "1191706624" is of course the result of

```
(product [2,7,7,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,8,8,8,9,9]) `mod` (maxBound :: Int)
```

and sure enough the result of the first part when run directly in ghci is the correct 4996238671872.

So, how can I have Haskell give me Integer product results (that I will turn to strings right away with show anyway)?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use

```
fromIntegral :: Int -> Integer
```

to promote an `Int` to an `Integer`. For similar future questions, you can use [Hoogle](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=Int%20-%3E%20Integer) to search for functions by type, which would have gotten you a closely related answer:

```
toInteger :: Int -> Integer
```